# Closest function in jQuery and extracting the elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a html fragment as follows:

```
<div id="samplediv">
  <ul>
   <li name="A">
     <a id="A">
   </li>

   <li name="B">
     <a id="B">
   </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have a text called:

```
var text = "B";
```

I have want to check if the text matches with any of the elements of li and add a class name **"disable"** for the anchor element not matching with text.
I my case I want to add a class called **"disable"** for

`<a id="A">`

This is what I have tried:

```
$("#samplediv li").each(function() {

 if($(this).name != text){
   $(this).closest("a").addClass("disabled");
}
});
```

But the thing here is `$(this).name` is evaluating to `"undefined"` . What is it that I am missing?

Edit: Due to typo ,had missed the  tag

Comment: html is invalid LI is child of UL

Comment: `this.name` can be used, but `name` attribute is using for `form` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues,

- `$(this)` returns a jQuery object which does not have `name` property, instead you can use `$(this).attr('name')`
- `.closest()` is used to find the ancestor element, but the `a` is a descendant of the `li` element, so you need to use `find()`

You can find all the `li` elements which does not have the given name and then find the `a` element within it like

```js
var text = 'B';
$("#samplediv li").not('[name="' + text + '"]').find("a").addClass("disabled");
```

```css
a.disabled {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="samplediv">
  <ul>
    <li name="A">
      <a id="A">a</a>
    </li>

    <li name="B">
      <a id="B">b</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = "B";
$("#samplediv li").filter(function() {//use filter
  return $(this).attr('name') != text;//use .attr() to get name attribute

}).find('a').addClass("disabled");//use find to get the anchor tag
```

```css
.disabled{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="samplediv">
  <ul>
    <li name="A">
      <a id="A">a</a>
    </li>

    <li name="B">
      <a id="B">b</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Comment: Though this is a valid answer, it does no explaining

Comment: @AndrewL i have comments in answer for clarification